# how to deploy nexus opensource webapp in tomcat?

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, nexus

I am trying to deploy nexus webapp in tomcat .. but i am stuck .. can anyone help ?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com or serverfault.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no need to use tomcat..
we can directly launch nexus repository on ur localhost ..